# best clojure repl?

Tags: clojure, clojure-repl

there is bunch of repl in clojure ?

1. lein repl
2. cursive clojure repl plugin inteljidea
3. gorilla repl newly launched
4. cider for emacs

is anybody having idea which one is good?

Comment: The answer is subjective and highly opinion based. The question might be closed for this.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Practically all Clojure REPLs mentioned are based upon [nREPL](https://github.com/clojure/tools.nrepl), and as such have the same backend functionality. The choice of REPL client frontend is usually driven by usecase:

1. Minimal REPL only needing JVM and Clojure jar, no nREPL client-server structure or leiningen `project.clj` integration:

   - Clojure REPL launched by `java -cp clojure.jar clojure.main`
2. Quick commandline checks or lightweight install for connection from commandline only systems:

   - [lein REPL](http://leiningen.org/), which uses [REPL-y](https://github.com/trptcolin/reply) as frontend
3. Working from the IDE of your preference:

   - [Cider](https://github.com/clojure-emacs/cider) (based on Emacs)
   - [Cursive](https://cursiveclojure.com/) (based on Intellij)
   - [Counterclockwise](https://code.google.com/p/counterclockwise/) (based on Eclipse)
4. Need for iPython notebook like interactive UI and persistence, graphical plots

   - [Gorilla REPL](http://gorilla-repl.org/)
   - [Session](https://github.com/kovasb/session)

Client maturity and functionality within these categories differ little, and are user preference based. However, choosing the right type of REPL by usecase makes all the difference, which is why most Clojure users switch between them when needed.